# what does []{0,3} signify in Stanford TokensRegex?

Tags: stanford-nlp

what is the significance of []{0,3}?

> ([ner: PERSON]+) /was|is/ /an?/ []{0,3} /painter|artist/

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokensregex.shtml):

> ```
> []        Any token
> ```

[...]

> ```
> X{n,m}    X, at least n times but no more than m times
> ```

Thus `[]{0,3}` matches up to 3 tokens.